# Wordpress Memory limit not increasing

Tags: php, server, apache, memory

I have set 1024M in `php.ini` file:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I have set it in `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfModule>
```

I have set it in `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '1024M');
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

But I still get the following error on a plugin page in my Wordpress admin area:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 61440 bytes) in /home/eroticnaughtines/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4212
```

And yes, all the files are in the root directory of my Wordpress installation.

Comment: Talk to your hoster what the maximum of your hosting is. If it's limited by the server you can't do anything but change hosting. I've never seen a simple managed hosting with 1GB of php memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create `.user.ini` file in root and put below code

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 256M
memory_limit = 500M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_vars = 500M
```

Try and let me know if any query.

Hope it will help!

Comment: .user.ini file already exists with that information.

Answer (score -1):

Adding

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '1024M');
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

before

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

in your `wp-config.php` file should do the trick.